# Is there a Stack Exchange site for asking questions about where a question goes?

Tags: discussion, meta, site-recommendation

Say if I had a question that I didn't know where to ask, say,

> How does myopia work?

I know it goes somewhere around [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/), but if someone (I) didn't know where to ask that, do we just ask on Meta Stack Exchange and hope for a redirect or something?

Comment: `[tag:site-recommendation-site-recommendation]`? So meta...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just ask about where it belongs here. We are, after all, the Meta where you ask questions about the entire network, and we get plenty of questions like this already.

Answer (score 5):

[site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) has lots of these questions.  They are appropriate for Meta.SE.

> if someone (I) didn't know where to ask that, do we just ask in the meta.stackexchange and hope for a redirect or something?
>   discussion

Asking *about* which Stack Exchange site would be appropriate.  Posting the *actual* question here and asking it for it to be migrated to the appropriate site would be inappropriate.